# Using events.patch in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a Google apps script to update an event. I tried using the path API like below:

```
  event_ins.setVisibility('private');
  Logger.log('Making event %s %s private %s',calendarId, event_ins.summary, event_ins);
  Calendar.Events.patch(event_ins,calendarId, eventID_ins);
```

I get the following error message:

```
11:28:30 AM Error  HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found.
```

I tried using the update method instead

```
Calendar.Events.update(event_ins,calendarId,eventID_ins);
```

I'm still getting the same error.

The examples in [Google's API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) does not use Google script. I tried searching example code and I found similar usage. For instance this is from [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpE15p83unk-Cg) :

```
event = Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, eventId, { 
    sendNotifications: true 
  });
```

I would appreciate any help to get this working.

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for retrieving the value of `eventID_ins`?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: When I was trying to come up with a minimal reproducible example, I found the problem. Tanaike, I was using eventID_ins=event_ins.eventID. The did not work. I used eventID_ins = event_ins.getId(). That worked. Thank you, Tanaike and Ruben.